# How to hide reference labels on the code editor of VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

The reference labels enclosed by red rectangles are distracting. How to hide them?

[image]

Comment: Oh my ghost, I found the solution. `CodeLens` is the name for this, it can be hidden via options menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may check out [Configuring Code Information Indicators in Visual Studio 2013](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/07/17/configuring-code-information-indicators-in-visual-studio-2013/)

and try this:

Tools--> Options --> Text Editor --> All Languages --> Code Information Indicators

[image]